# Issue found: Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form (Google Maps API - http://maps.googleapis.com)

Tags: android, google-maps, ssl, google-api, google-play-console

[image]

We received an email informing us that our application is not compliant with Google's policy and that an issue related to the data security section was identified. However, we noticed that the URL mentioned in the email, "http://maps.googleapis.com", is only used by the SDK we have incorporated into our application, and we have **no records of direct calls to that API** in our code. Also, we have ensured that the Google Maps SDK is updated to the latest available version.

Updating our form in Play Console to indicate that our app does not encrypt in transit is simple a not acceptable solution for us, we really try to keep all our remote API calls 100% safe and we always opt for *https* instead of *http*.

We wrote an email to Google about this and they replied with no significant new information. Basically a copy / paste of the original email we received from them.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with whatever SDK is calling that URL - if it's the Maps SDK, have you tried [contacting them](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/support), rather than the Play Store support? Or is it some other third-party SDK in your app that is calling this?